# Get content of specific Table cell and change text color

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, html, code-behind

I want to check if the content of a table cell starts with + or - and therefore make the text color green or red. How can I do that in code-behind?

Result should look like this:

[image: Table displaying stock change rate]

Comment: Put more details about the problem. How are you getting data in the table? Do you want it from jQuery or codebehin etc.

Comment: the user should fill it with the CKeditor control. I want to make a function in codebehind (c#) which checks the cells every 15 seconds  and adapting the colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very generic example for a single TextBox, with belonging Code-Behind (Not using MVVM):

XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="+0.25$" />
```

Code-Behind:

```
if (MyTextBox.Text.StartsWith("-"))
    MyTextBox.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
else
    MyTextBox.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
```